# (Calling Api) Created a json object but android studio throw a error which is "Type mismatch:inferred type is String but JSONObject? was eXpected"

Tags: android, json, xml, api, kotlin

```kotlin
val url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=myApiKey"
val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener {},
        Response.ErrorListener {}
    )

MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsonObjectRequest` is probably a `String` & not a `JSONObject`.

If it is in-fact a `String` then you can create a `JSONObject` like this:
`val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonObjectRequest)`